# Maven - Using last of double argument

Tags: java, maven, unix, cmd

I'm calling following command:

```
 mvn -s ../someLocation1/settings.xml -s ../someLocation2/settings.xml -X
```

Maven use settings.xml file from first `-s` argument, there is a way to force maven to use last argument of `-s`

Problem comes from our CI agent (bamboo) by deafult run every maven task with `-s` command, and we want to override this `-s` argument.

Comment: Why do you need to overwrite for a build the settings.xml configuration? Sounds a little bit weird...

Comment: If you need to overwrite a build setting you should split the two in user setting and global setting...

Comment: I need to overwrite it because this settings.xml contains user credentials to deploy artifact to Artifactory. Credentials in "first" settings.xml dosen't has this permissions.

Answer (score 1):

You should have only one `settings.xml` on your command line arguments.

Either change the path of the `settings.xml` in bamboo (so that the first argument is the correct `settings.xml`) or make sure that the first `settings.xml` contains all the credentials.

I do not know what you want to achieve by "hiding" the credentials in a second `settings.xml`. Our `settings.xml` lies in a directory on the build server so nobody except the build server admins can access it. Therefore, it is not dangerous to have usernames and passwords in there.